# Error CS0122 'AuthenticationOptions' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, inheritance, visual-studio-2015, owin, katana

I was following this [guide to write my own Katana authentication middleware](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/writing-an-owin-authentication-middleware/).

Now I encountered a problem when I'm writing the AuthenticationOptions. 
I get an "inaccessible due to its protection level" when I inherent from Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationOptions. The thing is that this class is protected, so it should not be inaccessible? I have tried to do a clean and rebuild, but I still get the same error. I must be missing something?

My class:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dummy
{
    public class DummyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions
    {
        public DummyAuthenticationOptions(string userName, string userId)
            : base(Constants.DefaultAuthenticationType)
        {
            Description.Caption = Constants.DefaultAuthenticationType;
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-dummy");
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
            UserName = userName;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public PathString CallbackPath { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string SignInAsAuthenticationType { get; set; }

        public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationProperties> StateDataFormat { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationOptions:

```
namespace Microsoft.Owin.Security
{
    internal abstract class AuthenticationOptions
    {
        protected AuthenticationOptions(string authenticationType);

        public AuthenticationMode AuthenticationMode { get; set; }
        public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
        public AuthenticationDescription Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inernal classes can be accessed only from the assembly they are declared in. Are you sure you are using the same version of `Microsoft.Owin.Security` that the author of the article is using? I've just opened the sources of the author's example from github, and everything looks fine there. And `AuthenticationOptions` class is public in that version of the library (2.0.1+).

Comment: I'm using latest stable (3.0.1). I'm getting the package with nuget if that is any help. I downgraded to 2.0.1 and it compiled. I guess the issue was that the class was internal, which it is not in 2.0.1, I wonder why though? Thank you helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `AuthenticationOptions` class was set to internal. I downgraded the `Microsft.Owin.Security` package from 3.0.1 to 2.0.1. Here the class is marked `public` so I was able to compile without problems.

Thanks to Dmitry Rotay